# How to make a form submit on div click using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I already tried this in single php file but doesn't work out, so i tried now in two separate php file one for form and another one for process.

How to submit the form on a div or link click?

Code i tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.web').click(function () {
        $("#g_form").submit();
        alert('alert');
    });
});
```

FORM

```
<form action="p.php" id="g_form" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="f1" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit!" name="submit"/>
</form>

<div class="web">click</div>
```

Here is the process file code **p.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['f1'])){
    echo $_POST['f1'];
} ?>
```

When i click the submit button the form is submitting but when i click the `.web` div it is not submitting the form even i get the alert message but not submitting.

What wrong am doing here? It'll be helpful if i get a idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[.submit() docs](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

> *Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method.
>   Name conflicts can cause confusing failures. For a complete list of
>   rules and to check your markup for these problems, see
>   [DOMLint](http://kangax.github.com/domlint/).*

You give your submit button a name of submit, which the above passage tells you will cause "confusing failures"

So if you accessed the dom element and looked at the `.submit` property you would see that since you name the button submit instead of `.submit`being a function its a reference to the buttons dom element

HTML

```
<form action="p.php" id="g_form" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="f1" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit!" name="submit"/>
</form>

<div class="web">click</div>
```

JS

```
//Get the form element
var form = $("#g_form")[0];
console.log(form.submit);
//prints: <input type="submit" value="submit!" name="submit"/>
```

And when you change the submit name

```
<form action="p.php" id="g_form" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="f1" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit!" name="psubmit"/>
</form>

<div class="web">click</div>
```

JS

```
var form = $("#g_form")[0];
console.log(form.submit);
//prints: function submit() { [native code] }
```

so simply give your submit button a different name that does not conflict with a form's properties.

Comment: THanks +1. Is this [0] array for form in js?

Comment: @rram, since jquery returns an array when selecting elements this just gets the underlying dom object from the jquery object. its a shortcut instead of having to do `$("#g_form").get(0);`

Comment: @rram, all jQuery selectors are also arrays. Even if it's one element, it's still an array. Thus, `document.getElementById("myId")` is has the identical result as `$("#myId")[0]`.

Comment: Sorry for asking questions then why people say for example $('.chart').something as jquery object and selectors instead of arrays @AlexanderMP

Comment: @rram, because it does more than an array. You can $('...').fadeOut() for example. You can't do that with arrays. This functionality is provided by jQuery. This is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger submit button click.

```
<form action="p.php" id="g_form" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="f1" value="">
<input type="submit" value="submit!" id="f_submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

<div class="web">click</div>



 $(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery('.web').click(function () {
        $("#f_submit").trigger( "click" );
          alert('alert');
    });
  });
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/awladnas/a6NJk/610/

Comment: Thanks +1. This works. It would be helpful to me if i know the reason why it was not working

Comment: Not sure exactly, guessing it would be because of the Name(submit) of the Input Submit. Use some other name and try.

Comment: Yes. It surely is related to that input field because either renaming it (see @Senthilmurugan answer) or removing it (see my answer) it starts working.

Comment: @rram : yes it was the problem the button name.

Comment: See my answer as to why this happens, when you use a form property name as the name of element it overwrites the form's property with that name

Answer (score 2):

HTML (provide a name for the form, strip the name from the submit):

```
<form action="p.php" name="g_form" id="g_form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="f1" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit!"/>
</form>

<div class="web">click</div>
```

JavaScript

```
//use jQuery instead of $ in the global scope, to avoid conflicts. Pass $ as parameter
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //use on(), as it's the recommended method
    $('.web').on('click', function () {
        //use plain JavaScript. Forms are easily accessed with plain JavaScript.
        document.g_form.submit();
        alert('alert');
    });
});
```

Comment: THanks +1 for the new way `document.g_form.submit();`

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the submit and Try,

```
<input type="submit" value="submit!" name="mySubmit"/>
```

Comment: Not sure about the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the submit from the form and try again:

```
<form action="http://test.com" id="g_form" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="f1" value=""/>
</form>

<div class="web">click</div>
```

I changed the action to a real URL and the method to a GET so something is seen changing.

### [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/b5XGU/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".web").live('click', DivClick);

function DivClick(){
    $("#g_form").submit();
}
```